# Emberjs subemenu in a menu

Tags: javascript, ember.js, menu

My goal is a following. I want to have a main navigation menu (navigation handlebar). In the menu 3 i want to have a menu with two submenus (menu3.submenu1 and menu3.submenu2).

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("menu1", { path: "menu1" });
  this.route("menu2", { path: "menu2" });
  this.resource('menu3', function() {
    this.resource('menu3.submenu1', { path: '/submenu1' });
    this.resource('menu3.submenu2', { path: '/submenu2' });
  });

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.NavigationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'navigation'

});
```

the templates:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{view App.NavigationView}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="navigation">
            <ul id="navigation">
                {{#link-to "menu1" tagName="li"}}
                    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Menu 1</a>
                {{/link-to}}       
                {{#link-to "menu2" tagName="li"}}
                    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Menu 2</a>
                {{/link-to}}
                {{#link-to "menu3" tagName="li"}}
                    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Menu 3</a>
                {{/link-to}}                          
            </ul>    
  </script>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="menu2">
  Menu 2
  </script>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="menu3">
                 {{#link-to "menu3.submenu1" tagName="li"}}
                    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Menu 3-1</a>
                {{/link-to}}
                 {{#link-to "menu3.submenu2" tagName="li"}}
                    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Menu 3-2</a>
                {{/link-to}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="menu3/submenu1">
  Menu 3 == submenu1
  </script>
```

I put togeather a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mehabivu/2/edit

Comment: what do you want??..question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an `{{outlet}}` helper in `menu3` template to display its route's resources.

Example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mehabivu/5/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="menu3">
                 {{#link-to "menu3.submenu1" tagName="li"}}
                    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Menu 3-1</a>
                {{/link-to}}
                 {{#link-to "menu3.submenu2" tagName="li"}}
                    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Menu 3-2</a>
                {{/link-to}}

                {{outlet}}
  </script>
```